# Exibir ID vinculado de um registro duplicado mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

Gostaria de saber se é possível mostrar os registros duplicados e quais os `id` que eles estão duplicados.

Exemplo Tabela:

[image: Tabela com 8 linhas e 3 colunas contendo nomes de empresas]

Gostaria de exibir os nomes duplicados, porém que ele também me informe o `id` junto.

Fiz a consulta abaixo:

```
select count(*) as contador, nome_F
  from comerciantes
 group by nome_f
having count(*) > 1
```

Entretanto desta forma ele só me mostra quantidade de duplicados e não o `id` vinculado.
[image: Tabela contendo 4 linhas e 2 colunas com quantidade e nome da empresa]

Quero que ele exiba não só a quantidade de duplicados, mas também o `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [GROUP_CONCAT](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/). Na *query* abaixo vai retornar o nomes duplicados, ao lado de uma lista de `id` concatenados:

```
select count(nome_f), nome_F, GROUP_CONCAT(id)
  from comerciantes
 group by nome_f
having count(nome_f) > 1
```

Você pode visualizar melhor no exemplo funcional:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43b86/5

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda.